# Angular-slickgrid custum Formatter - bootstrap ngbTooltip not working

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, slickgrid

I am using angular-slickgrid in my angular application with bootstrap 4. I am using custum formatter for one column say detail as below:

Custum formatter code in (cusum.formatter.ts file):

```
export const detailFormatter: Formatter = (row: number, cell: number, value: any, columnDef: Column, dataContext: any, grid?: any) => {
const template = `<button ngbTooltip="Details" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2 btn-floating btn-blue-grey btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></button>`;
return template; }
```

below is code for using the above custum formatter in angular-silkgrid :

```
 this.columnDefinitions = [{formatter: detailFormatter,  id: 'detail', name: '', field: 'detail', minWidth: 50,width: 50, maxWidth: 50}, ....other columns}
```

On running the application I have checked that I am unable to see the tootip 'Details'. So the problem is that bootstrap ngbTooltip is not working with custum formatter in angular-slickgrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I'm the author of Angular-Slickgrid.

You cannot use Angular directly in a Formatter, the reason is because this lib is a wrapper of a javascript/jQuery library and a formatter requires a synchronous function that returns a string (in html format) right away and Angular **does not** return right away, you need at least 1 cycle before it returns.

The answer is in this [Demo](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/angular-components) and the code for the [Component](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/examples/grid-angular.component.ts). You need to use an `asyncPostRender`

Taking code sample from that demo

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  prepareGrid() {
    this.columnDefinitions = [
      {
        id: 'assignee2',
        name: 'Assignee with Angular Component',
        field: 'assignee',
        filterable: true,

        // to load an Angular Component, you cannot use a Formatter since Angular needs at least 1 cycle to render everything
        // you can use a PostRenderer but you will visually see the data appearing,
        // which is why it's still better to use regular Formatter (with jQuery if need be) instead of Angular Component
        asyncPostRender: this.renderAngularComponent.bind(this),
        params: {
          component: CustomTitleFormatterComponent,
          angularUtilService: this.angularUtilService,
          complexFieldLabel: 'assignee.name' // for the exportCustomFormatter
        },
        exportCustomFormatter: Formatters.complexObject,
      }
    ]; 

    this.gridOptions = {
      asyncEditorLoading: false,
      enableAsyncPostRender: true, // for the Angular PostRenderer, don't forget to enable it
      asyncPostRenderDelay: 0,    // also make sure to remove any delay to render it
    };
  }
}
```

However, I strongly suggest you to consider using a plain html javascript Custom Formatters. The reason is because is simple, since a Formatter with Angular is defined as async, they are much slower (you will see them loading/rendered in the grid since it takes a cycle to render).

It works but yeah I strongly suggest to reconsider using only plain html Formatters (event though I added a demo, I never use Angular Formatters).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, yes a Formatter with Angular is defined as async, they are much slower. So I will also prefer using plain html javascript custum formatters.